# How do I get Authorization Code grant type to work?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I would like to use the Authorization Code Grant so authorization is via Google credentials only.
To do this I think I need to disable the Client Credentials Grant and make sure Authorization Code grant is enabled.

I have followed the examples given for [OAuth 2.0 with WSO2 Playground](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground) but I keep getting the error result "*invalid_grant, Provided Authorization Grant is invalid*".

I've started looking at the databases and see the *apimgt* (set up from [OAuth 2.0 with WSO2 Playground](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground)) database contains a table called *IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN*. This table lists the tokens and access codes and grant types amoung other things.
The access code I'm interested contains the setting "client_credentials" for the grant type. In fact all the rows in this table contains this setting for the GRANT_TYPE. When I change the grant type in the Store or the Identity Server the grant type in this database is not updated.

I'm stuck on this and need a little direction.

Does the database table *IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN* contains the actual grant types, or is this a 'red herring'?

Can Authorization Code Grant type work without client Credentials Grant?

How do I get Authorization Code grant type to work?

Comment: Here's a link to the log entries generated when trying to get access, https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkURPqBaUeJJrFQR7T4dbGjmFn-f

Comment: Update, the table IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN is populated but the table IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE is not. Still digging...

Comment: I got it working. It was my lack of understanding on the setup that was the issue, I was setting the call back url to the same value in all places when the backend url should have been, localhost:9443/commonauth